# MySQL connector with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio

I've been trying to use MySQL connector with Android Studio but I can't get it to work.

```
Error:PARSE ERROR:
Error:unsupported class file version 52.0
Error:...while parsing com/mysql/jdbc/JDBC42CallableStatement.class
Error:1 error; aborting
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

There are already few questions with the same problem but their solution isn't working for me.

Comment: Have you tried to change your mysql-connector jar version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using SQLite on Android instead of MySQL. Try this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm).

Otherwise use an [ORM](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO)(Object Relational Mapping), it will greatly reduce you to write SQL queries and is much efficient and cleaner to use.